# Run mode() function of each value in INT ARRAY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that holds an `INT ARRAY` data type representing some `features` (this is done instead of having a separate boolean column for each feature). The column is called `feature_ids`. If a record has a specific feature, the ID of the feature will be present in the `feature_ids` column. The mapping of the `feature_ids` are for context understanding as follows:

```
1: Fast
2: Expensive
3: Colorfull
4: Deadly
```

So in other words, I would also have had 4 columns called `is_fast`, `is_expensive`, `is_colorfull` and `is_deadly` - but I don't since my real application have +100 features, and they change quite a bit.

Now back to the question: I wanna do an aggregate `mode()` on the records in the table returning what are the most "frequent" features to have (e.g. if it's more common to be "fast" than not etc.). I want it returned in the same format as the original `feature_ids` column, but where the ID of a feature is ONLY in represented, if it's more common to be there than not, within each group:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  feature_ids integer[] DEFAULT '{}'::integer[],
  age INT,
  type character varying(255)
);

INSERT INTO test (id, age, feature_ids, type) VALUES (1, 10, '{1,2}', 'movie');
INSERT INTO test (id, age, feature_ids, type) VALUES (2, 2, '{1}', 'movie');
INSERT INTO test (id, age, feature_ids, type) VALUES (3, 9, '{1,2,4}', 'movie');
INSERT INTO test (id, age, feature_ids, type) VALUES (4, 11, '{1,2,3}', 'wine');
INSERT INTO test (id, age, feature_ids, type) VALUES (5, 12, '{1,2,4}', 'hat');
INSERT INTO test (id, age, feature_ids, type) VALUES (6, 12, '{1,2,3}', 'hat');
INSERT INTO test (id, age, feature_ids, type) VALUES (7, 8, '{1,4}', 'hat');
```

I wanna do a query something like this:

```
SELECT 
    type, avg(age) as avg_age, mode() within group (order by feature_ids) as most_frequent_features
from test group by "type"
```

The result I expect is:

```
type    avg_age most_frequent_features
hat     10.6    [1,2,4]
movie   7.0     [1,2]
wine    11.0    [1,2,3]
```

I have made an example here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rTP4w7264vDC5rqjef6Nai/1

Answer (score 0):

I find this quite tricky.  The following is a rather brute-force approach -- calculating the "mode" explicitly and then bringing in the other aggregates:

```
select tf.type, t.avg_age,
       array_agg(feature_id) as features
from (select t.type, feature_id, count(*) as cnt, 
             dense_rank() over (partition by t.type order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from test t cross join
           unnest(feature_ids) feature_id
      group by t.type, feature_id
     ) tf join
     (select t.type, avg(age) as avg_age
      from test t
      group by t.type
     ) t
     on tf.type = t.type
where seqnum <= 2
group by tf.type, t.avg_age;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ad46e73aa296982c418779a24a726cb2) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, while this is sure a solution, I am wondering if there could be something "simpler" done.